# reload or refresh page to get the updated Api response Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I'm new to Getx and i have been using Getx for API calls. I have been calling the Controller of specific API while loading the page. But when i update the API, like adding new data to API and when i come back to my screen which shows list of produts, its not been updating. Its not reloading the page. it just showing the previous loaded page. How can i call the API again or just can i reload the page?

```
 var productListController;
  // final productListController = Get.find<ProductListController>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    productListController = Get.put(ProductListController());
    super.initState();
    print("done");
  }
```

i need to reload the page so that i can fetch updated API data!

```
class ProductListController extends GetxController {
  var productList = List<dynamic>().obs;
  var isLoading = true.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchproductList();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void fetchproductList() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var details = await ProductApi.productList();
      if (details != null) {
        productList.value = details["products"];
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
}
```

how can i update ? how can i call the fetchproductList to get updated??

Comment: You can either use `setState()` to update the data if its added OR you could use `obs` & `Obx` reactive combination in the GetX Package to update the widgets when the data changes. Check example: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx#counter-app-with-getx

Comment: wrap the productListController assignment in a setState() call.

Comment: i tried using setState(() {
                    ProductListController().fetchproductList();
                  });   when im updating the product but its not working

Answer (score 0):

If the data that you're trying to display on the Widgets is in `productListController`, then you can wrap it inside `setState()` when the value is updated. Calling setState should rebuild `Widget build()` to load the updated values in the Widgets.

```dart
setState((){
  productListController = Get.put(ProductListController());
});
```